# Angular js preloader

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Как сделать прелоадер для ангуляра(роунтинг) который будет пропадать только после полной загрузки страницы ?

Comment: Было бы хорошо если бы вы описали пошагово то что хотите сделать, а то задаче не понятная, от того и ответов нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гугля, я сразу наткнулся на очень простой модуль `ngProgress` http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/:

```
const app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngProgress']);

app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) => {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            template: `
                <h1>Главная</h1>
                <a href="/">Главная</a>
                <a href="/blog">Блог</a>
            `
        })
        .when('/blog', {
            template: `
                <h1>Блог</h1>
                <a href="/">Главная</a>
                <a href="/blog">Блог</a>
            `
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);

app.run(['$rootScope', '$injector', ($rootScope, $injector) => {
    const ngProgress = $injector.get('ngProgressFactory').createInstance();

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', () => { 
        ngProgress.start();
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', () => {
        ngProgress.stop();
    });
}]);
```

Пример с кастомным прелоадером, тут все намного проще:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', ($rootScope) => {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', () => { 
        $rootScope.loading = true;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', () => {
        $rootScope.loading = false;
    });
}]);
```

В `index.html`:

```
<style>
    .spinner {
        position: absolute;
        // какие-то стили...
    }
</style>

<div class="spinner" ng-if="loading">
    <img src="/to-some-gif-spinner">
</div>

<div ng-view></div>
```

Но еще есть маленькая проблема - это быстрый роутинг, поэтому ваш спинер может и не отображаться, как вариант добавляем `setTimeout`:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$timeout', ($rootScope, $timeout) => {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', () => { 
        $rootScope.loading = true;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', () => {
        $timeout(() => {
            $rootScope.loading = false;
        }, 500);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Я такое видел, явно я задал не корректно вопрос, мне надо что бы мой собственный прелоадер (спинер для примера) показывался

Comment: @ДмитрийМинин, добавил пример

Comment: он у меня пропадает быстрее чем страница загрузиться

Comment: при изначальной загрузке или роутинге?

Comment: изначальной, а при роунтинге в конце particles начинает странно себе вести

Comment: Каким то образом теперь все появилось но particles странно себя введет )

Comment: дай те телеграм )